# How do i make my code in kotlin read data from the firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make an app that reads data from the firebase firestore and then shows in a screen that same data
The problem the data only appears when shown in log but i want the in text(string)
Can anyone help me understand how to do it

I already tried many videos explaining but none of then work so my last option is really ask in here for help.

Here is the code

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun DB () {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val collectionReference = db.collection("Inventário")
        .document("Bloco E")
        .collection("Sala E0.05")

    val data = mutableStateOf(mapOf<String, Any>())
    val job = remember { Job() }

    remember {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val documentSnapshot = collectionReference.document("Computador").get().await()
            try {
                data.value = documentSnapshot.data ?: mapOf()
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("Firestore", "Error retrieving data", e)
            }

        }
    }

    Column() {
        data.value.forEach { (key, value) ->
            Text("$key: $value")}
    }
}
```

And here is the database structure:

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: already did that

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-display-data-from-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-49ee736dc07d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreJetpackCompose).

Comment: Your post didn't really help much because i already tried using the same website and it didn't work but thanks for trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to use `remember` on your `MutableState` (and also suppressed the lint warning with (`@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")`)):

```kotlin
val (data, setData) = remember { mutableStateOf(mapOf<String, Any>()) }
```

Also, using GlobalScope in Android is not recommended. Consider using a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect) instead:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DB () {
    val db = Firebase.firestore
    val collectionReference = db.collection("Inventário")
        .document("Bloco E")
        .collection("Sala E0.05")

    val (data, setData) = remember { mutableStateOf(mapOf<String, Any>()) }

    LaunchedEffect(collectionReference) {
        try {
          val documentSnapshot = collectionReference.document("Computador").get().await()
          setData(documentSnapshot.data ?: mapOf())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          Log.e("Firestore", "Error retrieving data", e)
        }
    }

    Column() {
        data.value.forEach { (key, value) ->
            Text("$key: $value")}
    }
}
```